# How to choose between "can" and "might" in "The service {can/might} be surly"

Tags: modal-verbs, present-tense

I'm learning modal verbs now using a grammar textbook. There are different topics. One of them is a topic about possibility. I went through the rules part and now I'm doing exercises after it where one asks to rewrite a sentence so it has a similar meaning. I did some but here is one which is tricky for me:

> The service in this restaurant is sometimes surly.

It's the present. For present possibility there are two rules:

1. "we use 'can' to talk about things which are generally possible".
2. "we usually use 'may', 'might' and 'could' to talk about specific possibilities".

So my answer was:

> The service in this restaurant might be surly.

But the right answer from the textbook is

> The service in this restaurant can be surly.

Why is it general possibility? We are talking about a specific place here so I think it's about specific possibility.

It will be nice if someone explains what general and specific possibilities mean. What is the difference between them? Of course, I know the difference between something either being general or specific but as you can see it's not enough to do the exercise correctly:) So maybe for native speakers it's more certain.

Comment: Artem, "surely" is an adverb. Service in a restaurant cannot be "surely". What do **you mean** by that? That answer in that textbook is meaningless. [example of how to use surely in a sentence: **She will surely go** to that school, not this one.]

Comment: "The service in this restaurant is sometimes surely" doesn't make any sense. The word **surely** makes no sense here. Where did you find this sentence? It's not correct. It seems to be an error.  Did you mean **surly**?

Comment: @BillyKerr I don't think service can be surly either. Only people are surly.

Comment: @Lambie - I agree 100%, but it can't be **surely** either because that would be complete nonsense. The restaurant staff could be surly though.

Comment: @BillyKerr The OP corrected it and I had already said it was nonsense with surely.

Comment: @BillyKerr I apologize for this typo. It's the autocomplete on my phone. It's 'surly'.

Comment: I think you would really need to say the staff are surly, the waiters are surly, or the servers are surly because it's usually people we describe as surly.  I don't think it works well to say the service is surly. To describe the service directly, perhaps you could say it's bad, slow, poor, awful, dire, etc.

Comment: @BillyKerr It's actually not my sentence. It's a sentence from an exercise of the textbook I use to learn English:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's simplify the sentence a little bit:

> 1. Pat is sometimes surly.

This is a general statement about how Pat is sometimes. They might not be surly right now, but they have been known to be surly in the past so it's possible they will be in the future.

> 2. Pat **can** be surly.

I would understand this to have the same meaning as #1, or "I know Pat and every once in a while they are surly."

> 3. Pat **might** be surly.

I would understand this to mean "I'm not sure, but it's possible that Pat will be surly when you talk to them." An example in context would be something like, "Pat had to pay their taxes today and that always makes them grumpy. They might be surly, but don't take it personally."

Back to your sentence:

> The service in this restaurant might be surly.

I would say something like this if my husband and I were trying to decide to go to a restaurant and I had heard rumors about bad service, but I wasn't really sure what kind of service we might receive. I probably wouldn't use "surly" though; I think that's not a very common word for restaurant service unless you're a food critic writing a review.

> The service in this restaurant can be surly.

I might say this if I had been to the restaurant more than once and some of those times the service wasn’t good. “I like the food there, but the service can be surly.”

Comment: Why not can? X can be nice, X can be surly. But yes, I wouldn't say service is surly, only servers.

Comment: @Lambie I’m not sure I understand your question. *She can be nice.* In general, she’s capable of being nice. *She might be nice.* There’s a possibility she will be nice, but we’re not sure one way or the other, or, *She might be nice this time, even though she’s usually not.*

Comment: You used might and my question is why not use can? Either would work. She can be nice. is just another example with can.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you for your answer.
I can say "He can work late" which means I know it is possible he does, for example, because he often did. It's more general because it can be Sunday and he's at home now but there's just a talk about it.
I can also say "He might be working" meaning he's never worked late but today in the morning he said he'd possibly be late because of work and it's 8 pm now and he's not yet at home.
I can also say "He might be working" meaning he often works late and now it's 8 pm and he's not at home so it's possible he's still in the office.
Have I got it or not?:)

Comment: @ColleenV I think I can also add another example to yours if I correctly understand. I think I can say "The service in this restaurant might be surly" when, let's say, I've been in this restaurant and I know the service there can be surly but sometimes it's not and once taking a walk with my friend we can be passing this restaurant and he can suggest to go there because he's never been there yet and I can say to him "The service here might be surly" because I don't know what service we might get this time. So I can talk in general and I use 'can' but I'm talking about this specific visit now.

Comment: @ArtemMalyshev “He can work late” means he’s capable of working late without any more context, for example, he doesn’t have to be home to take the kids to soccer. It wouldn’t mean that he has a habit of working late. I think there is a difference between “he can be annoying” and “he can fly a plane” for example.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, I agree 'He can work late' is more about his ability to work more than, let's say, 8 hours a day. I wanted to mean he sometimes works late, more than 8 hours a day, because he sometimes has to due to some reasons at work, not because he's able to. But what about my example with the service?=) In your answer there's an example with 'can' to talk in general. An example with 'might' which is more specific. But my example resembles yours with 'might' and Pat where at the same time there is a more general idea and the 'always' shows it whereas talking about a specific situation.

Comment: Your second comment that I upvoted is fine - that's the correct understanding. I wouldn't use "He can work late" to mean "Sometimes he works late" though. I would say "He sometimes works late, especially if his project is [behind schedule](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/behind%20schedule "not according to schedule : late")." It may be because trying to use "can" for that situation would confuse the listener/reader about whether I was talking about his ability or his habit. I don't know a rule that would explain the difference in usage though.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you very much for your help! Now I understand it more clearly.

Comment: @ColleenV I was trying to practice these grammar rules providing my own examples. And now I have a feeling that for general situations 'to be + adjective' is only acceptable. This is why it's strange to say 'He can work late' trying to mean what I wanted to mean when you think it's more about ability and now I agree with it because I couldn't produce any.

Comment: I'm glad it helped - when I get more time I will edit the answer to include the information in the comments.

Comment: @ColleenV Ok, thanks